# CSP Refuse to load base64 image

Tags: ionic2, content-security-policy

I am working on an ionic 2 application and receiving error message from the console stating that refuse to load image and script because it violates the CSP rules.

As for the image, it is being stored is the database as blob. I am able to get the base64 values but could not display it on the application.

**Index.html**

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
       img-src 'self' data: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com;
    " />
</head>
```

**Component Html**

```
<ion-card>
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{storePhoto}}">
</ion-card>
```

Error Message : `Refused to load the image 'unsafe:data:image/png;base64,' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com".`

**Update**

I tried using `DomSanitizer` from angular but hits another error. This is my updated code.

**Component ts**

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
constructor(public DomSanitizerService : DomSanitizer){}
```

**Component ts**

```
<img [src]="_DomSanitizationService.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(data:image/png;base64,{{storePhoto}})" />
```

`Uncaught(in promise):Error: Template parse errors:Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}})`

Comment: Did you actually add the CSP tag like that your component html like that? Because it needs to be in your `index.html` file

Comment: Please use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44912876/edit to edit/update your question and add the exact error message you’re seeing in your browser devtools console

Comment: @Andreas Gassmann Yes. I add it in the main `index.html` not the component html. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message indicates you need to add `https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com` to your policy:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
img-src 'self' data: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com;
script-src 'self' https://maps.googleapis.com;
" />
```